# Why STL algorithm find() doesn't work on maps?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

Is there any explanation why find() algorithm doesn't work for maps and one have to use map::find instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. It does work on maps, but you need to compare against a `map::value_type` (which is `std::pair<const map::key_type, map::mapped_type>`), not the key type.
2. Because map.find takes a key and returns a key/value pair iterator.

Comment: Just to clarify, map's `value_type_ is `pair<key_type, mapped_type>`.

Comment: According to the standard section 23.3.1, for a std::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator>, key_type is Key, but value_type is pair<const Key, T>. The reason is that once the value has been inserted the key of insertion must be immutable, or else the order invariant could be broken

Answer (score 3):

As noted elsewhere, it does work, but the type is the key/value pair, so you need to supply a functor/function to do the comparison. (You could probably do it with a custom operator==() overload too, though I've never tried such a thing)

However you probably do want to use the map member function find() anyway since it will give the O(logN) lookup, the algorithm std::find() is O(N).

Additional: I think you could also use std::equal_range/lower_bound/upper_bound() with a map ok, these are also O(LogN).

Comment: A custom operator== is neither allowed nor necessary. Use find_if innstead.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean equal_range? With a map, you should use the member functions lower_bound, upper_bound and equal_range. The std equivalents may provide logarithm number of comparisons, but they require linear time to walk over the elements of a container.

Comment: Are you sure about the linear walk? I thought that you'd get a log walk just fine, if you have random access iterators.

Comment: if you have random access iterators, yes, but if not, you'll have to do linear number of steps. std::map does not provide random access iterators.

Comment: Yep, you quite right on that point, forgot map's iterators are only bidirectional.

Answer (score 1):

You should read "Effective STL" by Scott Meyers for more info on subjects like these.

"Item 43: Prefer member functions to algorithms with the same name"

For why the member function exists and why you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Meyers also recommends using STL algorithms as opposed to writing your own loops (Item  43 in 2001 edition). For a simple type you should be able to use just

```
find(mmap.begin(), mmap.end(), "value")
```